# Not all of my RAM is showing up

Tags: ram, bios, 21.04

I have an issue where not all my RAM is showing up in the settings but it is in the BIOS so I know it’s not a faulty stick. It’s a Lenovo idea pad slim 3 running 21.04. I don’t have any swap. It’s low voltage DDR4. It used to be 8 GB but has now dropped to 5.6.

```
[sudo] password for harley: 
[    0.005081] check: Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.005466] ACPI: Reserving FACP table memory at [mem 0xb9576000-0xb957610b]
[    0.005468] ACPI: Reserving DSDT table memory at [mem 0xb956a000-0xb9572900]
[    0.005469] ACPI: Reserving FACS table memory at [mem 0xbe621000-0xbe62103f]
[    0.005470] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xba696000-0xba69b418]
[    0.005471] ACPI: Reserving MSDM table memory at [mem 0xba157000-0xba157054]
[    0.005472] ACPI: Reserving BATB table memory at [mem 0xb9f79000-0xb9f79049]
[    0.005473] ACPI: Reserving HPET table memory at [mem 0xb9575000-0xb9575037]
[    0.005474] ACPI: Reserving APIC table memory at [mem 0xb9574000-0xb9574107]
[    0.005475] ACPI: Reserving MCFG table memory at [mem 0xb9573000-0xb957303b]
[    0.005476] ACPI: Reserving IVRS table memory at [mem 0xb9569000-0xb956913d]
[    0.005477] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb9567000-0xb956819b]
[    0.005478] ACPI: Reserving CRAT table memory at [mem 0xb9566000-0xb956680f]
[    0.005479] ACPI: Reserving CDIT table memory at [mem 0xb9565000-0xb9565028]
[    0.005480] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb9564000-0xb9564539]
[    0.005481] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0xb9563000-0xb9563037]
[    0.005482] ACPI: Reserving FPDT table memory at [mem 0xb9562000-0xb9562033]
[    0.005483] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb955b000-0xb955c3a5]
[    0.005484] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb9559000-0xb955a54d]
[    0.005485] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb9556000-0xb9557f43]
[    0.005486] ACPI: Reserving BGRT table memory at [mem 0xb9555000-0xb9555037]
[    0.005487] ACPI: Reserving UEFI table memory at [mem 0xbe61f000-0xbe61f165]
[    0.005488] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb9561000-0xb9561712]
[    0.005876] Early memory node ranges
[    0.021394] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.021396] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009e000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.021397] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.021398] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.021400] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x09c00000-0x09cd0fff]
[    0.021402] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x09f00000-0x09f0afff]
[    0.021403] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xae680000-0xbc77dfff]
[    0.021404] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbc77e000-0xbe77dfff]
[    0.021405] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbe77e000-0xbe7fdfff]
[    0.021406] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbe7fe000-0xbfffffff]
[    0.021407] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc0000000-0xf7ffffff]
[    0.021408] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.021408] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfd1fffff]
[    0.021409] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd200000-0xfd2fffff]
[    0.021410] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd300000-0xfebfffff]
[    0.021411] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfecfffff]
[    0.021412] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed7ffff]
[    0.021413] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed80000-0xfed80fff]
[    0.021413] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed81000-0xff7fffff]
[    0.021414] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff800000-0xffffffff]
[    0.088914] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
[    0.482744] Freeing initrd memory: 106608K
[    0.486371] check: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    0.797269] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2036K
[    0.798068] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2696K
[    0.869206] Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2036K
[    0.869327] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 76K
[    1.303801] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 2920510 KiB
[    1.303802] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 KiB
[    1.303924] [drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    1.303928] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
[  959.360804] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  959.381133] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory

             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5704        2436         132          88        3134        2888
Swap:             0           0           0
```

And I do have an integrated graphics card.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the terminal output of `free -m` and `dmesg | grep -I memory`? This is *probably* a case of your integrated graphics device having a large amount of memory dedicated to it, which is controlled in the UEFI/BIOS, but adding the output of the above terminal commands will confirm whether this is the case or not 

Comment: i editied my question

Comment: It is exactly as describe in the previous comment. Everything is normal and expected. Nothing to see here. You may or may not (probably not) be able to change the amount assigned as VRAM in UEFI.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying